# Chart editor / designer / wizard component for the web

Tags: asp.net-mvc, charts, javascript

I'm searching the web for a chart component (JavaScript) that not only displays the chart but also allows a user to define it:

This component should be very extensible and allow the user to define his own chart (without any coding knowledge):

- Choose the type of chart (bar chart, stacked chart, pie chart)
- Choose a datasource from a list
- Choose the series using the specified datasource
- Ideally display a preview
- Save this definition so that it can be displayed in a widget on the home page

Searching the web I've come across [amcharts](http://www.amcharts.com/) which is awesome. It  even has a live editor which unfortunately is available only online and is not downloadable (is not a product by itself).

The component should be easy to integrate in a web application (which is a ASP.NET MVC app) so most likely should be based on JavaScript, HTML 5 and SVG.

Is there any such a component (free or paid)?

Comment: We have built a chart editor based on Google Visualization API. Happy to discuss more about it. See here: https://vida.io/pages/google-charts. You can contact me at phuocd@vida.io.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking to create CAN be done, and realistically it can be done with any charting library.

Creating the UI to access the right part of the library is going to take a good amount of work. You'd have to write out the selection tools for chart types, features, and the functionality you choose to allow.  If you allow styling, that is an additional layer.

Choosing the right library is going to come down to

- ease of implementation
- flexibility of the API
- do they provide the right click events to allow the user to proceed to the next step
- supporting chart types that you need

Some other ideas that come to mind that you may consider as partial solutions are:

https://chartio.com/product/tour

White label of Tableau

Ducksboard/Geckoboard

I'm on the team at [ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com) so if you'd like to talk to our team here about this, feel free to reach out.